# MySQL Select query with condition using list in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a mysql table named “table1” with 3 columns named “column1”, “column2” and “column3” and I have a list named “list1”.
I want to select all rows where list1 contains the cell value of column2. I tried in several ways to make the query string, but I failed. Please help. I tried as

```
Dim mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=1234;database=Share"
    mysqlconn.Open()
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE " & list1.Contains & "('" & column2 & "');", mysqlconn)
    Dim datatable As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(datatable)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = mysqlconn
```

Comment: How do you intend to use a vb.net list in an sql query string? What I suggest you do is load all the data to a datatable then query the datatable for the data you want.

Comment: @preciousbetine it's usually preferred to let the server filter results whenever possible. It would be easier to use LINQ for example if OP used Entities, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

What you almost did, but didn't quite do, was use [MySQL IN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx) to see whether a value is in a list.

If column2 is numeric,

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column2 in (1,2,3);
```

```vb
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column2 in (" & String.Concat(",", list1) & ");"
```

If column2 is text,

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column2 in ('1','2','3');
```

```vb
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column2 in (" & String.Concat(",", list1.Select(Function(i) $"'{i}'").ToArray()) & ");"
```

Comment: I didn't think of combining the `in` statement with `String.Concat`. Nice answer.

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind help. The problem has been solved. Thanks again.